# UserDefaults between Objective-C and Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, string, object, userdefaults

Just trying to be extra careful here...

If I have an app that saved a value in UserDefaults like this in Objective-C:

```
NSString *newString = textField.text;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: newString forKey:@"textKey"];
```

Would this be the proper way of checking whether this value exists when I release an update to the app that is now coded in Swift:

```
if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "textKey") as? String) != nil {
     print("There is a string")
} else {
     print("No string exists") 
}
```

I try to use .string(forKey:) and .bool(forKey:) since they've been introduced, but is it safest since this was saved as an object to pull it out as an object and then test it with "as? String"?

Trickier version of the same question:

An NSMutableArray of NSDictionary objects was saved as an object in UserDefaults

```
if let oldData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "theData") as? [NSMutableDictionary] {

}
```

Will NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary be interchangeable here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[NS]UserDefaults` is backed by a plist and a dictionary. The Objective-C string was saved to the plist as a `<string>Some Text</string>`.

That same plist loaded in Swift gives a string for that key.

So you should have no issue using `UserDefaults.string` to read the value stored with Objective-C. Of course you still need to verify the value actually exists.

```
if let str = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "textKey") {
    print("Found \(str)")
} else {
    print("No string for key")
}
```

Even if the original value isn't a string, using `UserDefault.string` is safe. It will simply return `nil` for non-string values.

With regard to `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary`, note that `UserDefaults` only retrieves immutable `NSDictionary`. You can't read an `NSMutableDictionary` (or array) from `UserDefaults`.

Note you can safely use a Swift dictionary to read the original `NSDictionary`. No need to use Objective-C classes.

Comment: You *can* read an array from UserDefaults, and it appears to correctly load the array of dictionary objects whether I use if let oldData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "theData") as? [NSMutableDictionary] { } or if let oldData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "theData") as? [NSDictionary] { }. As you mentioned, these are immutable Dictionary objects.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't load an array. I stated that they would be immutable. And there is no reason to use the Objective-C classes. Load the dictionary directly into a Swift dictionary.

Comment: Marking this answer as correct. I can use the Swift 'Dictionary' as the value type for the objects in the array if I add these generic arguments: if let oldData = defaults.object(forKey: "theData") as? [Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>] { }

Answer (score 2):

Yes your solution is safe, if the value you saved in the Objective C code is indeed a `String` type than, when you retrieve that value from `NSUserDefaults`, it will be a String and will correctly be coerced to a String by the `?` operator of your Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way (in Swift and Objective-C) is to [register](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) each key value pair to provide a default value. This default value is considered until the value is changed the first time.

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValues : [String : Any] = ["textKey" : "", "dictionaryKey" : [:]]
userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

Now you can safely write

```
if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "textKey")!.isEmpty {
     print("No string exists") 
} else {
     print("There is a string")
}
```

Of course the developer is responsible for overwriting a value with the same type.

---

`NSMutableDictionary` is not related to Swift `Dictionary`. To get a mutable object just use the `var` keyword.

```
var dictionary = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "dictionaryKey") as! [String:Any]
```