# Userdefaults set in Swift files return nil when accessed from objective c file under same target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

Userdefaults value set in swift module returns nil when accessed from Objecive-c files under the same target.

```
defaults?.setValue(data["details"]["equipmentLocationRefreshInterval"].intValue, forKey: "equipmentLocationRefreshInterval")
 defaults?.setValue(data["details"]["hasEquipmentDeviceLocationConfigured"].boolValue, forKey: "hasEquipmentDeviceLocationConfigured")
defaults?.synchronize()
//data["details"]["equipmentLocationRefreshInterval"] = 30
//data["details"]["hasEquipmentDeviceLocationConfigured"] = TRUE
```

When accessed from objective-C classes

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"equipmentLocationRefreshInterval"];
//returns nil
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"equipmentLocationRefreshInterval"];
//returns <nil>
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasEquipmentDeviceLocationConfigured"];
// returns true when set as true in swift module.
```

I am failing to understand this behavior of Userdefaults. I am able to access one key's value and not others.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44171550/14733292

Answer (score 0):

Swifts `UserDefaults.setValue` looks:

```
open func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
```

So it can get optional of any type and you should check that you pass not nil value.

First check that your optional `defaults` is not nil and then verify `data["details"]["equipmentLocationRefreshInterval"].intValue` because there are three optionals one by one: two of them to get a value from your dictionary and last to convert your stored type (is it NSString?) to `Int` with `intValue` and each of these optionals can be nil.